# The QPSQL driver can not loaded

Tags: qt, psql

if i try to run my qt application on windows 7, the console print:

```
QPSQL driver not loaded ... available driver:...QPSQL...
```

After that, i've tried to include the following paths to the windows path variable

```
C:\psql32\bin;C:\psql32\include;C:\psql32\lib;
```

The application can connect to the psql db and all works fine. How can i fix this problem, without to install the psql software on all pc's. ?

Best regards, chris.

Comment: okey, i paste all the PSQL *.dll files from `C:\psql32\bin;C:\psql32\include;C:\psql32\lib;` to my application folder, but i think this is a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: I guess you'll need to deploy at least the PSQL client library (whatever it's called). Check with Dependency Walker what exact DLLs are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to use the drivers from Postgres. At least in the version I use (commercial, 4.8.4, Win)
Qt provides the drivers in the directory `<QTDIR>\plugins\sqldrivers.`

When the application runs on the computer, where Qt is installed, nothing should be done explicitly - Qt should find the drivers.

When the application is deployed on a computer without Qt-installation, I copy release versions of the files found in `<QTDIR>\plugins` to `<MyAppExeDir>\plugins`.

Besides Sql drivers, same problem could apply also to jpeg an other pluggable components.

P.S.:
Make sure, not to mix Qt-dlls from one computer with Qt-plugins from other computer, even if the versions are the same.